# Fixing double running of javascript code in different tabs

Tags: javascript

I created a little timer which runs from 30seconds down to 0 and saved in the localStorage, butthen restarts after a event and again begins at 30secs. But if I open 2 tabs of the same page the code runs double. That means that after 1 seconds the timer jumps for example from 30 to 28.

```
    function timer(){
    localStorage.setItem("time", 30);
    
    setInterval(function(){
        localStorage.setItem("time", localStorage.getItem("time") - 1);
        timerPlace.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("time");
        if(localStorage.getItem("time") < 0){
            localStorage.setItem("time", 0); 
            timerPlace.innerHTML = "TIME TO PLACE !";
        }
    }, 1000);
    
    
    if(localStorage.getItem("time") === null){
        localStorage.setItem("time", 30);
    }
    
}
```

I already thought of getting the number of opened tabs and do something with this. Or maybe there is a way to only run a javascript code in one tab.

Comment: localStorage is per origin (the website url) not per tab, so one tab is setting localStorage to one number and the other is setting it to another nummber.

Comment: the script could append some time based string to the index and constantly reference that throughout the function, each tab would have its own timer

Comment: If the data only needs to persist for the session you may be able to use session storage instead, as this is not shared between tabs. Should be an easy replacement as all the available methods on local storage are also available in session storage.

Comment: But does session storage save this local for every tab

Comment: Every tab should have the same time

Comment: Each tab would have it's own session storage, and each page can edit it's own without it affecting other tabs. The downside of course being that as soon as the user navigates away or closes the tab, the data will be removed. So if you want the timer to pickup where the user left off, this will not work. Not sure if that's what you were asking?

Comment: Or are you saying that all tabs should be running the same counter based on the localstorage? Like if one tab sets a 30 second timer and it counts down to 20s, a newly open tab should also display 20s and count independently of the other tab?

Answer (score 2):

Store the start time of your count in `localStorage`. Then calculate the distance from it in seconds. when reach 30, clear that value.

This example is without using localStorage because not allowed in a stack snippet.

```js
var start = (new Date()).getTime();
var ind_id
ind_id = setInterval(function() {
  var now = (new Date()).getTime()
  var diff_in_seconds = Math.round((now - start) / 1000)
  if (diff_in_seconds >= 30) {
    cancelInterval(ind_id)
    return;
  }
  timerPlace.innerHTML = (30 - diff_in_seconds)
}, 1000)
```

```html
<div id="timerPlace"></div.>
```